# JQuery not firing on first click, but fires on second click

Tags: jquery, html

I am attempting to get a button to run AJAX to update my database on MySQL, then fire off a JQuery function to load (basically refresh) a different file so that there is no page refresh needed. I am fairly new to JQuery & AJAX so I may be doing this completely wrong. I have already gotten AJAX to work with updating the database, but JQuery seems to only be registering the second click.

I have searched a ton through Stack Overflow, but I haven't found anything that seems to work for me. The most common solution I've found is:

```
$('#display_details').on('click', '.addpa1', function() {
        $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');
});
```

This isn't working for me (or I'm not using it properly).

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.editProject').click(function(){
        $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');
    });
    $('.addpa1').click(function(){
        $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');
    });
    $('.addpa2').click(function(){
        $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');
    });
    $('.rempa2').click(function(){
        $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');
    });
    $('.rempa1').click(function(){
        $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');
    });
   })
```

**HTML**

```
<a name='addpa1' href='#' class='btn btn-success btn-sm addpa1' id='User.1' role='button' data-proid='2' title='Make PA #1' data-toggle='tooltip'>Make PA #1</a> 
<div id="display_details"></div>
```

I gave an example of one button to limit the clutter. The rest are identical other than the class name which goes along with their click function.

**Additional JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( "#showToast" ).click(function() {
$('.toast').toast('show');
});

});

$('#modal').on('shown', function () {
   $("#modal-content").scrollTop(0);
});
```

I'm having to click twice for the JQuery to register.

Comment: Does your tooltip work on hover or on click? If on click, then it may be conflicting with the same event.

Comment: @blupointmedia I removed the tooltip and it didn't solve it.

Comment: I get an inkling it's something to do with `role=button` and `a` tags in conjunction. Instead of having `onclick` events, could you just have `onclick='function()'` in the `a` tag? Better still, does it HAVE to be an `a` tag? Can you make it a div or something? i think they're probably conflicting by calling the `a` tags `onclick` and then the `button` on click afterwards or something dumb like that

Comment: Could you please tell me if substituting this: `<a name='addpa1' href='#' class='btn btn-success btn-sm addpa1' id='User.1' role='button' data-proid='2' title='Make PA #1' data-toggle='tooltip'>Make PA #1</a> ` with this: `<div name='addpa1' href='#' class='btn btn-success btn-sm addpa1' id='User.1' role='button' data-proid='2' title='Make PA #1' data-toggle='tooltip'>Make PA #1</div> ` has the same issue?

Comment: @EGC I did this and it seems to be loading the page every time I click it but it messed with the AJAX, I'm not sure if divs can send POST through AJAX..

Comment: Hm, no it should be okay. Sorry, I fogot to remove the 'href' from this, try this now? `<div name='addpa1' class='btn btn-success btn-sm addpa1' id='User.1' role='button' data-proid='2' title='Make PA #1' data-toggle='tooltip'>Make PA #1</div>`

Comment: I was calling two separate functions with one button which screwed with it. I combined the two functions and it works now! I appreciate your help!

I've been working on this for so many hours and can't believe the solution is this simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I was calling two seperate functions for each button (one for AJAX, other for JQuery). Putting the JQuery function contents into the AJAX function solved the issue.

Thank you to everyone who helped me out on this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated the `Prevent Default` characteristic of `onclick` events before?

Sometimes, the default can cause quirky behaviour like it not working on the initial click.

You could try changing your `onclick` event to something like this (for each `onclick`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addpa1').on('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');   
  });
})
```

Or something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.editProject').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php');
      });
    });
```

Read about **Prevent Default** here: [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

I think it also might be worth noting this section of **ARIA Compliance** - [ARIA button role Example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/button/button.html)

Where this is considered a **"Non-compliant Example"**:

```
<a href="#"
     role="button"
    >
  Show alert
</a>
```

So there's a chance your example has semantic issues in terms of ARIA.

Let me know if that helps any?

Comment: I haven't seen the even.preventDefault() before but I just attempted it and it had the same behavior as before.

Comment: All of my code (there's tons), or are there certain parts you want?

Comment: Hm, probably anything JS/Jquery !

Comment: I added the additional JS to the post, but it's just something for Bootstrap Modals that I was testing because they weren't working before.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if the element isn't attached to the dom prior to you trying to click it. Can you try this below to see if it works on one click and if you get the console.log?

```
$('body').on('click', '.addpa1', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('.addpa1 clicked');
    $('#display_details').load('project_member_list.php', function() {
        console.log( 'Load was performed.' );
    });
});
```

What happens if you console.log the completed request? See above.

Comment: I clicked it and got the .addpa1 clicked console log. It's still not registering the first click though.

Comment: Did you get the console.log on the first click?

Comment: Yes, do you think the AJAX could be interfering with this?

Comment: I updated my answer to add in a console after load. See if that triggers on 1 click.

Comment: I figured it out. The AJAX function was messing with the JQuery function. I appreciate your help!